# can't connect to DB - EADDRNOTAVAIL

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, tedious

I have a simple node.js app that can't connect to a SQL Db.

Web server is Azure Web App, running node.js and using [Tedious](https://github.com/pekim/tedious) for SQL. 
DB is Azure SQL Database.

This is the detailed error:

> {
>     message: 'Failed to connect to xxx.database.windows.net:1433 - undefined',
>     code: 'ESOCKET' }
>
> Thu Jan 14 2016 08:05:05 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time): Unaught exception: ConnectionError: Connection lost - connect **EADDRNOTAVAIL**
>       at Connection. (D:\home\site\api\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:797:26)
>       at Socket. (D:\home\site\api\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:33:15)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:88:20)
>       at Array.1 (net.js:301:14)
>       at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:190:38)

It works on my machine, and the funny thing is that is also works on another Azure Web App! I tried restarting this web app and what not... What's this error means?

Comment: I had a similar problem before and it turned out I just had my connection string misformatted. I had even looked at it, but missed a minor error. Could you triple check your connection string? It helped me to log it to console. I eventually caught it when I manually passed it to connection string parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the issue, but failed. So I searched some keyworks like `EADDRNOTAVAIL` for NodeJS & Tedious, then I found the page https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/6833.

It inspired me that the issue might be caused on some specified version node. You can find the node version of the bad WebApp at the url `https://<the_bad_webapp_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env`, and compare with the fine one.

> You can see alll node version supported by Azure at the url `https://<node webapp name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/diagnostics/runtime` of Node WebApp.

If their node version are different, you can try to specify the node version of Tedious works fine for the bad webapp, please refer to the doc https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/nodejs-specify-node-version-azure-apps/ to know how to do it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you! I compared node versions and updated to the latest and it works. Great instincts!