# Node.JS Redis connect EADDRNOTAVAIL error in Microsoft Azure Web App

Tags: node.js, azure, redis, client, azure-web-app-service

I have a Node.js app deployed to a Microsoft Azure Web App and I can't seem to fix the following error:

```
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
> Error: Redis connection to
> <insertRedisHostNameHere> failed -
> connect EADDRNOTAVAIL
>     at errnoException (net.js:670:11)
>     at connect (net.js:548:19)
>     at Socket.connect (net.js:613:5)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (net.js:77:12)
>     at RedisClient.create_stream (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\redis\index.js:218:31)
>     at new RedisClient (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\redis\index.js:169:10)
>     at Object.createClient (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\redis\index.js:906:12)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\server.js:8:20)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
>     at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
```

The code that is causing this error is:

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient(17397, '<hostname>', {enable_offline_queue: false});
client.auth('<password>', function(err){
});
client.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('connected to redis');
});
```

I haven't been able to find a working solution, any help is greatly appreciated.

Additionally, I am able to run the same code on my localhost and local Redis cache without any problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by updating the version of Node JS in package.json. (Refer to this question for more details: [can't connect to DB - EADDRNOTAVAIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34785147/cant-connect-to-db-eaddrnotavail?rq=1))